# Filter Grid from a public property

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a public property witch looks like this

```
  public string SelectedCountry
        {
            get { return this.cmbCountry.SelectedValue; }
        }
```

Where i receive what the user has selected in the RadComboBox.

Now I want to filter my gird by this selected value how can I do this ?

On the gird page I prepared method like this witch is triggered when the user clicks on a button (apply filter)

```
protected void Af_FilterButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {    
       jobFilter.SelectedCountry.Where() //jobFilter is my custom control 
        }
```

I thought that I have to do something like this ?

Thanks for help and fast answer !

Comment: the grid and your combo are in same page?

Comment: @SoftSan the combo is part of the custom control that I created  .and ofc the control connected with the gird page. I can acces my control with jobFilter. (what ever) so i guess yes it is in the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter your list/data by applying condition like:

```
protected void Af_FilterButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{    
   if(!string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(jobFilter.SelectedCountry))
   {
     var data= YourDataSource.Where(c=> c.YourCountryField == jobFiler.SelectedCountry).ToList();
     YourGrid.DataSource= data;
     YourGrid.DataBind(); // or Rebind()
   }
}
```

Comment: THX for your answer !!! I just have one question I use as a DataSource a  EntityDataSource so I receive a error message that there is no 'Where' on a  EntityDataSource

Comment: see this... http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-3 It will help you to understand it properly.